# How to find a value index in a drop down by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down list and I want to get each option index by its value in jquery.

```
<select name="CustomerId" id="CustomerId">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

How to do this?

Comment: what will be the desired output ??

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: @palaѕн I havent tried anything and I just needed a sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this solution :

```
$('#CustomerId').change(function(){    
  var val = $(this).val();
  // option should be element of #CustomerId
  var index = $('option[value="'+val+'"]', this).index();
  alert(index);
});
```

Read this [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/wmpv5jyn/)